# Create a modal dialog box in PHP-file1 (insert.php) displaying data depending on if statements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I want to build a modal dialog box which will inform user that his input was incorrect.I have created one php file(insert.php). The insert.php has 3 if statements.So depending on which if statement php runs then the modal box shall display the specific message.For now I alert the user with javascript window.alert but I don't like it..
Here are the codes of insert.php

form:

```
form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

          <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Αριθμός Κάρτας</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_number" autofocus="autofocus" required></div>
                            </div>


                 <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>


          <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Όνομα</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required></div>
                            </div>



                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

       <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Επώνυμο</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" required></div>
                            </div>

                 <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

       <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Διεύθυνση</label>

        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" placeholder="Οδός" name="address" class="form-control" required></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" placeholder="Περιοχή" name="area" class="form-control" required></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><input type="text" placeholder="TK" name="tk" class="form-control" required></div>
                            </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary demo1" type="submit">OK</button>
                                </div>
</form>
```

if_statements after insert_statements:

```
    if($_SESSION['id'] == $row_select['store_id'] && $row_select['active']==1){

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Η κάρτα που επιλέξατε έχει ενεργοποιηθεί ήδη. Πατήστε ΟΚ για νεα εισαγωγή.");</script>'; 



                }



     else if($_SESSION['id'] != $row_select['store_id']){


     echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Δεν έχετε δικαιοδοσία   σε   αυτόν τον αριθμό κάρτας. Πατήστε ΟΚ για νεα εισαγωγή.");</script>'; 



                }





 }else if  {
             echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Μη έγκυρος αριθμός κάρτας. Πατήστε ΟΚ για νέα εισαγωγή");</script>';



}
```

Comment: i recomand you sweet alert javacript plugin https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _but I don't like it_? They way it looks? the way the code works? What don't you like.

Comment: I meant the appearance of js alert.Thanks @B.Kevin it was helpful!

Comment: i propose you seetalert beacause you can change the css of the alert as you wish you could also use modal from bootstrap ,materialize or foundation. its a good base.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!I think I'll keep sweetAlert for the reason you said..Thanks again!